# How to create separate taxonomy page for different custom post types

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created 2 custom post types : property and agent. For this 2 custom post types i registered a shared custom taxonomy called "city".

My problem is that i need to to have 2 different taxonomy pages for each custom post type.

For example:
home.com/city/jersey-city/ use taxonomy.php and in there i use a query to show only property post types in "jersey city".

I need to create a similar template (and link) to show only agent post types in "jersey city".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional tags inside the taxonomy.php file to display different content depending on the post type.

```
if ( is_singular('your_post_type_name') ) {
    ( your code )
} elseif( is_singular('your_other_post_type_name') ) {
    ( your code )
} else {
    ( your code )
}
```